# How can I delete duplicate numbers in a list (Python)?

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a list :

```
words = ['1,2,3,4',
         '5,7,8,4',
         '1,2,3,9']
```

And my aim is to create a new list from words, but without duplicate numbers.

Here an example of what i would like to have!

```
new_list=[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9]
```

I did it :

```
words = ['1,2,3,4',
         '5,7,8,4',
         '1,2,3,9']

new_list = []
for i in words :
    if i not in new_list:
        new_list.append(i)
print(new_list)
```

But I got again same number in my list :

```
['1,2,3,4', '5,7,8,4', '1,2,3,9']
```

EDIT :

I would like do same thing but with real words, like it:

```
[" apple is not good",  "mongo is delicious",  banana is very good"]
```

and my new list must be every words of these phrases who are unique.
Here an example of my results I want:

```
["apple,is,not,good,mongo,delicious,banana,very"]
```

Like you can see, I got only unique words from phrases of the list.

Comment: you have words and every word is unique. May be you want to check characters instead?

Comment: Yes, i want check characters in my complete list

Comment: You say that new_list=[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9] is what you would like to have. Is this correct? Is that what you want, or is it new_list=['1','2','3','4','5','7','8','9']?  Big difference. The first is a list of numbers. The second is a list of strings.

Comment: Why is `banana` missing from your result?

Comment: sorry it was a mistake from me

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the elements of `words` with `itertools chain` module, then the set() method to eliminate all duplicates:

```
import itertools
words = ['1,2,3,4','5,7,8,4','1,2,3,9']
c = list(set(itertools.chain(words[0].replace(',',''),words[1].replace(',',''),words[2].replace(',',''))))
new_words = [int(x) for x in c]
new_words.sort()
print(new_words)
```

> Result

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

### For the Update

```
import itertools
words = ["apple is not good",  "mongo is delicious",  "banana is very good"] 
new_words = list(set(itertools.chain(words[0].split(' '), words[1].split(' '), words[2].split(' '))))
print(new_words)
```

> Result

```
['not', 'mongo', 'is', 'apple', 'good', 'very', 'delicious', 'banana']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to use extend,  not append. And also split each line. Convert to "set" to remove duplicate items
words = ['1,2,3,4',
             '5,7,8,4',
             '1,2,3,9']

new_list = []
for i in words :
        new_list.extend(i.split(','))
new_list = list(set(new_list))
new_list.sort()
print(new_list)
```

**or**

keep the order of elements

```
    words=['apple,banana,orange', 'apple, mango']

    new_list = []
    for i in words :
            new_list.extend(i.split(','))
    result =[]
    for i in new_list:
        if i not in result:
            result.append(i)
    
    print(result)
```

Comment: ty , but your second example doesn't work,  i guess a duplicate of apple in my final list

Comment: it works, I just output the wrong list. it must be print(result)

Comment: y exactely, i did bad, i wanted say that it didn't work if you got it : ['apple banana orange' , 'apple mango']

Answer (score 0):

```
words = ['1,2,3,4',
         '5,7,8,4',
         '1,2,3,9']

new_list = []
for w in words :
    for i in map(int, w.split(',')):
        if i not in new_list:
            new_list.append(i)
print(new_list)
```

The trick is extracting the digits from each *word* in your list. Each `word` is a string series of numbers separated by commas.  So, `w.split(',')` splits each string of comma-separated numbers into a list. The `map()` function applies the `int()` method to each number string converting it into a numeric value. Then that value is added to the new_list if it is not already there.

This solution also handles numbers greater than 9.

Also, as an example to help understand `map`:

```
"1,2,3,4".split(",") --> ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

and

```
map(int, ["1", "2", "3", "4"]) --> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```